# I have a dataframe of two columns, "PID7' and "ideo5" .I want to find the count of individual combinations between the two columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of two columns, "PID7' and "ideo5" .I want to find the count of individual combinations between the two columns.

pid7 ideo5
1      6     3
2      2     2
3      2     3
4      6     3
....

for example I want to find the count of combination of pid7 and ideo5,eg pid7:6 and ideo5:3 has a count of 2 , pid7:2 and ideo5:2 has a count of 1, pid:2 and ideo5:3 has a count of 1 and so on..
This would be needed to draw a graph like as following which would show the count of PID7 based on ideo5.
The graph would show PID7 and IDEO5 as 2 and so on ina bar chart.

[image]

Comment: 1) It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). 2) Include the code that you have tried to solve the problem. 3) Ask only 1 specific question per post.

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that for counting unique rows in a `data.frame` you may use `group_by_all()` followed by `count()`, both in the `dplyr` package. Here, it seems you want to use the unique values as well for plotting, so I propose an alternative with `tidyr`s `unite()` function whose values you can use directly as x-axis.

---

**Solution #1**

So, one easy possibility is to use the `unite()`-function from the `tidyr` package to create distinct pairs of columns and then use `table()` and `as.data.frame` to convert it to a `data.frame` that `ggplot()` can work on.

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(pid7 = c(1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 6), 
                 ideo5 = c(6, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3))
```

**Code**

```
bars <- df %>% 
           tidyr::unite("P", pid7:ideo5, sep = ",") %>% 
                       table %>% 
                               as.data.frame
```

**Output**

```
   . Freq
1 1,6    1
2 2,2    1
3 3,2    2
4 3,4    1
5 6,3    1
```

Then you can apply some `ggplot()` command, e.g.

```
ggplot(x = ., y = Freq) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

to arrive at

[image]

---

**Solution #2**

It seems likely though that you wish to create bar plots for *each unique* value of `pid7`. If so, we can create a list of tables for which you can subsequently generate the barplots like so,

```
df_list <- df %>% 
             group_split(pid7) %>% 
                   lapply(., function(x){x %>% 
                                           group_by_all %>% 
                                                        count})
```

Now you have in `df_list` as many `data.frame`s as there are unique values in `pid7`. For each you can now use `ggplot()` like

```
ggplot(df_list[[3]], aes(x = ideo5, y = n)) + 
              geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5)
```

[image]

Here, you have the barplot of all frequencies for all combinations of `pid7 = 3` with all values of `ideo5`.